# No insert na tabela está inserindo tudo, até o que eu não quero

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-service, linq, expressões-lambda

Quando dou um `savechanges()`, grava em todas as tabelas e gostaria de apenas uma. Como eu faço? As tabelas `Acao` e `ProximaAcao` também insere registro.

```
public T_TarefaParceiro geraIdParceiro()
{
    WEBEntities db = new WEBEntities();
    T_ParceiroOs osParceiro = new T_ParceiroOs();
    T_TarefaParceiro tarefa = new T_TarefaParceiro();
    T_ParceiroTarefa _tarefa = new T_ParceiroTarefa();
    T_Acao t = new T_Acao();
    T_ProximaAcao tp = new T_ProximaAcao();
    int _idAcao = 0;
    int _idProxima = 0;

    try
    {
        var tipoEstabelecimento = new List<int>{2,3,4,5,6};

        if (geraIdNovoPdv() == true)
        {
            var novo = db.T_PDV.Join(
                db.T_CRM_StatusPDV, t1 => t1.CNPJ, t2 => t2.DE_Cnpj,
                (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
                .Where(c => c.t2.DT_TransacaoV == null && tipoEstabelecimento.Contains(c.t1.IDTipoEstabelecimento))
                .Select(i => new { i.t1.CNPJ });

            var acao = db.T_Acao.Join(db.T_ProximaAcao,
                t1 => t1.IDAcao, t2 => t2.IDAcao,
                (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
            .Where(a => a.t1.IDAcao == a.t2.IDAcao && a.t1.IDAcao == 7)
            .Select(i => new { i.t1.Acao, i.t2.ProximaAcao, i.t1.IDAcao, i.t2.IDProximaAcao});

            foreach (var lista in novo)
            {
                osParceiro.PdvNovo = 1;
                osParceiro.Cnpj = lista.CNPJ;
            }

            foreach (var lista in acao)
            {
                osParceiro.AcaoParceiro = lista.Acao;
                osParceiro.ProximaAcao = lista.ProximaAcao;
                _idAcao = lista.IDAcao;
                _idProxima = lista.IDProximaAcao;
                t.Acao = lista.Acao;
                tp.ProximaAcao = lista.ProximaAcao;
            }

            tarefa.CNPJ = osParceiro.Cnpj;
            tarefa.IDAcao = _idAcao;
            tarefa.IDProximaAcao = _idProxima;
            tarefa.T_Acao  = t;
            tarefa.T_ProximaAcao = tp;

            db.T_TarefaParceiro.Add(tarefa);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else if (geraIdPdvV99() == true)
        { 
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string erro = ex.Message;
    }

    return tarefa;
}
```

Fiz aqui, seguindo a orientação do Cigano e agora o browser não mostra. Acho que tem a ver com o XML de retorno.

```
t.IDAcao = lista.IDAcao;
t.Acao = lista.Acao;
tp.IDProximaAcao = lista.IDProximaAcao;
tp.ProximaAcao = lista.ProximaAcao;
```

E chamei assim:

```
tarefa.T_Acao = t;
tarefa.T_Acao = t;
```

O que realmente pode estar acontecendo?

É um web service REST. A Interface desse método é essa:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(
            Method = "GET", // Tipo de request
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, // Identação do retorno
            UriTemplate = "abreos" // Url do serviço, onde cada {} = parametro
            )]//Filter para tratar REST
        T_TarefaParceiro geraIdParceiro();
```

Como eu construo o XML não sei, apenas um WS REST que ele monta esse XML de acordo com a resposta do método, certo? Não tenho esse domínio do assunto, rs.

Comment: Eu ri com esse título. Já te respondo.

Comment: Às vezes até o título fica difícil de escolher

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que você está abrindo dois objetos em teoria destacados do contexto, aqui:

```
foreach (var lista in acao)
{
    osParceiro.AcaoParceiro = lista.Acao;
    osParceiro.ProximaAcao = lista.ProximaAcao;
    _idAcao = lista.IDAcao;
    _idProxima = lista.IDProximaAcao;
    t.Acao = lista.Acao;
    tp.ProximaAcao = lista.ProximaAcao;
}
```

Estas variáveis `_idAcao` e `_idProxima` não são necessárias. Quando você faz esta atribuição:

```
tarefa.IDAcao = _idAcao;
tarefa.IDProximaAcao = _idProxima;
```

O contexto entende que são objetos novos. Como a tarefa é nova, essas duas linhas não são necessárias. Você pode atribuir os Ids apenas dos objetos já existentes:

```
tarefa.T_Acao  = t;
tarefa.T_ProximaAcao = tp;
```

Como possivelmente esse objeto que está sendo inserido está bem incompleto, você terá que carregar ele de novo. O retorno fica assim:

```
return db.T_TarefaParceiro.AsNoTracking().Include(t => t.Acao)
                                         .Include(t => t.ProximaAcao)
                                         .SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == tarefa.Id);
```

Comment: desse jeito o browser não exibe o xml de retorno.

Comment: Coloque na sua pergunta como você monta esse XML pra eu melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Perdoe minha ignorância, mas isso aí é o retorno do método? E os demais campos? Confesso que dei uma boiada nisso.

Comment: É o retorno. O que se faz ali é recarregar o registro fora do contexto e devolvê-lo. Os métodos `Include()` forçam a carga explícita dos dados de `Acao` e `ProximaAcao`.