# problema com update Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Esse é meu método atualizar:

```
public dynamic Atualizar(TEntity obj)
{
    dynamic data = null;
    using (ClassContexto ctx = new ClassContexto(ClassMaster.conexao()))
    {
        try
        {
            ctx.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;                    
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            data = "200";
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            data = e.EntityValidationErrors;
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            try
            {
                data = erro.InnerException.ToString();
                return data;
            }
            catch
            {
                data = erro.Message.ToString();
                return data;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Tenho uma classe Poi, que tem uma coleção de contatos. Para salvar, passo um objeto do tipo Poi com uma coleção de contatos. Funciona certinho.

O problema é para fazer update, passo o mesmo objeto Poi (com uma coleção de contatos) para o método acima, mas ele só altera a tabela Poi. Tem algo errado no método ?

---

Esse é o método de teste. Veja a forma que populo os objetos:

```
  [TestMethod]
    public void updatePoiContato2()
    {           

        poiModel.t0031_id_poi = 56;
        poiModel.t0030_id_tipo_poi = 2;
       // poiModel.t0030_id_tipo_poi = poiModel.t0030_id_tipo_poi;
        poiModel.t0031_razao = "TESTE UPDATE" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        poiModel.t0031_fantasia = "TESTE UPDATE" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        poiModel.t0031_cnpj_cpf = "12.935.236/0001-97";
        poiModel.t0031_ie_rg = "234234324234";
        poiModel.t0031_situacao = 1;
        poiModel.t0031_dt_cadastro = poiModel.t0031_dt_cadastro;
        poiModel.t0031_alldata = poiModel.t0031_razao + poiModel.t0031_fantasia + poiModel.t0031_cnpj_cpf + poiModel.t0031_ie_rg;


        PoiContatoModel model1 = new PoiContatoModel();
        model1.t0031_id_poi = 56;
        model1.t0033_id_contato = 6;
        model1.t0033_nome_contato = "TESTE UPDATE";
        model1.t0033_tipo_enum = "CELULAR";
        model1.t0033_valor_enum = "41-9174-3185";

        PoiContatoModel model2 = new PoiContatoModel();
        model2.t0031_id_poi = 56;
        model2.t0033_id_contato = 7;           
        model2.t0033_nome_contato = "TESTE UPDATE";
        model2.t0033_tipo_enum = "CELULAR";
        model2.t0033_valor_enum = "41-9174-3185";

        ICollection<PoiContatoModel> contatos = new List<PoiContatoModel>();
        contatos.Add(model1);
        contatos.Add(model2);

        poiModel.Contatos = contatos;            

        var result = poiDto.save(poiModel, "100", "a");
        Assert.AreEqual(true, result.Contains("200"));
    }
```

Comment: Os contatos possuem alterações também? Ou apenas a entidade "Poi"?

Comment: os contatos tb possuem alterações, veja como estou populando o objeto :

Comment: [Melhor você dar uma lida no Tour do Site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pra evitar de ter conteúdo apagado aqui. O Stack Overflow não é um fórum.

Answer (score 3):

De fato não vai funcionar para a edição. Quando você faz:

```
    PoiContatoModel model1 = new PoiContatoModel();
    model1.t0031_id_poi = 56;
    model1.t0033_id_contato = 6;
    model1.t0033_nome_contato = "TESTE UPDATE";
    model1.t0033_tipo_enum = "CELULAR";
    model1.t0033_valor_enum = "41-9174-3185";

    PoiContatoModel model2 = new PoiContatoModel();
    model2.t0031_id_poi = 56;
    model2.t0033_id_contato = 7;           
    model2.t0033_nome_contato = "TESTE UPDATE";
    model2.t0033_tipo_enum = "CELULAR";
    model2.t0033_valor_enum = "41-9174-3185";

    ICollection<PoiContatoModel> contatos = new List<PoiContatoModel>();
    contatos.Add(model1);
    contatos.Add(model2);

    poiModel.Contatos = contatos;
```

Você está recriando seus dois contatos, e não atualizando os contatos já existentes. Por mais que as informações sejam as mesmas (até com os Ids mencionados), o Entity Framework não entende assim por conferir que as listas de contato não são as mesmas.

O correto seria o seguinte:

```
var poi = contexto.Pois.Include(p => p.Contatos).SingleOrDefault(p => p.t0031_id_poi == 56);
poi.t0030_id_tipo_poi = 2;
// poiModel.t0030_id_tipo_poi = poiModel.t0030_id_tipo_poi;
poi.t0031_razao = "TESTE UPDATE" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
poi.t0031_fantasia = "TESTE UPDATE" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
poi.t0031_cnpj_cpf = "12.935.236/0001-97";
poi.t0031_ie_rg = "234234324234";
poi.t0031_situacao = 1;
poi.t0031_dt_cadastro = poiModel.t0031_dt_cadastro;
poi.t0031_alldata = poiModel.t0031_razao + poiModel.t0031_fantasia + poiModel.t0031_cnpj_cpf + poiModel.t0031_ie_rg;

var contato1 = poi.Contatos.SingleOrDefault(c => c.t0033_id_contato == 6);
contato1.t0033_nome_contato = "TESTE UPDATE";
contato1.t0033_tipo_enum = "CELULAR";
contato1.t0033_valor_enum = "41-9174-3185";

var contato2 = poi.Contatos.SingleOrDefault(c => c.t0033_id_contato == 7);
contato2.t0033_nome_contato = "TESTE UPDATE";
contato2.t0033_tipo_enum = "CELULAR";
contato2.t0033_valor_enum = "41-9174-3185";

var result = poiDto.save(poi, "100", "a");
Assert.AreEqual(true, result.Contains("200"));
```

Aliás, há uma série de más práticas advindas de vícios de desenvolvimento de outras metodologias, a saber:

## Propriedades de *Model* não devem ter o mesmo nome de colunas do banco

O Entity Framework é agnóstico, ou seja, não é montado para funcionar apenas em cima de um esquema de banco de dados relacional. Qualquer coisa pode ser fonte de dados (até um arquivo de texto bem estruturado, em teoria). Ainda assim, se você quiser mudar as colunas de nome, pode fazer isso usando *Attributes*. Por exemplo:

```
[Column("t0033_id_contato")]
public int ContatoId { get; set; }
```

Também é possível mudar o nome da tabela em banco.

## DTO's não persistem objetos

[DTO's são análogos aos *Models*, com lógica reduzida. Veja a definição](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_de_Transfer%C3%AAncia_de_Dados). A diferença entre um DTO e um *Model* é que o *Model* explicita as relações entre outros *Models*, as condições de validação de cada campo e propriedades adicionais montadas a partir de campos de dados.

Possivelmente o que você quis usar ali é um Repositório, mas [já falei algumas vezes aqui que o Entity Framework já é um repositório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+reposit%C3%B3rio), então este esforço não faz sentido.

## Não se altera Id's na edição de um *Model* no Entity Framework

Para alterar um objeto advindo de outra entidade no Entity Framework, você não deve fazer por Id. Deve selecionar o objeto da entidade estrangeira e atribuir o objeto mesmo. [Aqui explico o motivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32344/controller-edit-inserindo-valores/32365#32365). [Aqui explico de outra forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18962/no-insert-na-tabela-est%C3%A1-inserindo-tudo-at%C3%A9-o-que-eu-n%C3%A3o-quero/18974#18974).

Comment: Caro amigo, suas dicas foram de extrema importancia. Muito obrigado

Comment: Evite deixar suas perguntas abertas. [Veja aqui como usar o site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour).