# EF6 erro de EntityValidationErrors em propriedade preenchida

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework-6, validação, model-validation

Estou com um problema semelhante em duas aplicações ASP.NET com Entity Framework.

Quando tento atualizar uma entidade que já possui todos os atributos obrigatórios preenchidos recebo uma exceção de `EntityValidationErrors`, no entanto essa propriedade que esta descrita no `validarion` esta preenchida.

O mais estranho é que se coloco o breakpoint e verifico os atributos do objeto eles estão todos preenchidos e não causa o erro.

Em uma das aplicações estou contornando esse problema fazendo a propriedade receber ela mesma ou simplesmente acessando a propriedade e jogando seu valor em uma variável qualquer:

```
ComentariosBlog model = _comentariosBlogNegocios.GetById(idComentatio.Value);

if (model == null)
    return HttpNotFound();

model.Ativo = status.Value;
var teste = model.Publicacao; //<----Contorno
idPost = model.PublicacaoId;
_comentariosBlogNegocios.Salvar(model);
```

Já tenho um bloco de Try Catch que trata esse erro, o problema é que o objeto esta com todas as propriedades obrigatórias preenchidas e tenho que fazer uma "gambi" para que ele não gere erros como esta no código acima! O simples fato de acessar a propriedade e jogar ela em uma variavel qualquer já para de dar erro, mas preciso de uma solução mais correta para esse problema, como falei isso é somente um "gambi"!

Segue abaixo os detalhes do erro que é gerado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesta imagem podemos ver que a propriedade mencionada já esta preenchida:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui é a mensagem de erro dentro do try catch:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como corrigir o EntityValidationErrors](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17644/como-corrigir-o-entityvalidationerrors)

Comment: Já existe um tratamento de erro para saber qual a propriedade que o EF diz que não esta preenchida. O problema é que essa propriedade já esta preenchida e não é um simples problema de tratamento de EntityValidationErrors.

Comment: Preciso que você explique na sua pergunta como é feito este tratamento de erros. Há diversos tipos de validação que são feitos pelo `DefaultModelBinder`, não apenas o do campo preenchido ou não.

Comment: Boa tarde @CiganoMorrisonMendez, desculpe a minha ignorância no assunto mas eu já havia feito a validação como foi recomendado na publicação [link]http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17644/como-corrigir-o-entityvalidationerrors[link]. No entanto quando coloco o breakpoint e verifico as propriedades do objeto que estou tentando salvar, a propriedade que é apontada pelo DbEntityValidationException é uma propriedade que possui valor, mas se antes do SaveChanges() eu colocar uma variável teste recebendo o valor da propriedade o código não gera exceção.

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece em `ve.ErrorMessage`, na solução já mencionada?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez fiz uma edição na pergunta com os prints dos erros, não sei se isso ajuda?

Comment: Coloque por favor o seu `Model` na pergunta. Me chamou a atenção uma coisa na sua tela.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez você diz a minha entidade conforme print que inseri agora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu *Model* está errado. A propriedade de navegação:

```
public virtual PublicacaoBlog Publicacao { get; set; }
```

Não pode ser decorada com `[Required]` porque ela não será salva. O correto é `PublicacaoId` receber a decoração, porque este sim será salvo.

Já este preenchimento:

```
var teste = model.Publicacao; //<----Contorno
```

Atesta como tem coisa errada no seu projeto inteiro. É fácil de ver por aqui:

```
ComentariosBlog model = _comentariosBlogNegocios.GetById(idComentatio.Value);
...
_comentariosBlogNegocios.Salvar(model);
```

**O Entity Framework já implementa um repositório e NÃO é necessária a implementação de uma camada de "serviços", "negócio" ou qualquer coisa que seja, porque isso é papel do *Controller* fazer**. Eu escrevo extensivamente sobre isso há tempos, então vou mencionar de novo:

- [Entity Framework DDD Infra repositório Genérico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40577/entity-framework-ddd-infra-reposit%c3%b3rio-gen%c3%a9rico/40585?s=3|2.2070#40585)
- [Unidade de trabalho (Unit of Work) com repositório](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33280/unidade-de-trabalho-unit-of-work-com-reposit%c3%b3rio/33285?s=6|1.8803#33285)
- [Lugar em que devem ficar métodos de interação do CRUD com o banco em ASP.NET MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43637/duvida-mvc-asp-net-crud/43682?s=13|0.2185#43682)
- [problema com update Entity Framework 6](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58425/problema-com-update-entity-framework-6/58446?s=21|0.1249#58446)
- [Camada de Aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31664/camada-de-aplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o/31668?s=23|0.1059#31668)

Não adianta falar que "o MVP tal falou que é boa prática". Não, não é.

- Aplicar DDD no MVC não é boa prática;
- Aplicar camada *Service* em projeto MVC não é boa prática;
- Isolar *Controllers* e *Models* em DLL's diferentes não é boa prática;

O que você faz na linha que marquei é fazer o proxy dinâmico virar um objeto, que preenche corretamente a chave estrangeira do objeto, e que portanto salva. Para resolver, coloque o `[Required]` no campo correto para ele, ou seja:

```
[Required]
public int PublicacaoId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez, muito obrigado mesmo! Isso explica vários problemas que estou tendo no outro projeto. Eu imaginava que estava fazendo tudo corretamente e nem imaginava que estava cometendo um grande erro na arquitetura. Gostaria de agradecer também pelos links esta ajudando muito a esclarecer algumas outras dúvidas!!!